# Which database to use for highly-connected data model with frequent schema changes?

Tags: graph-databases, rdbms, database, nosql

I am currently working on a project, where we use web mining (web crawlers) to build up a company database. At the moment we employ PostgreSQL as our main database, however, I feel it will cause a lot of problems in the future, because as our crawler develop and extract more data we'll see many schema changes/additions.

Some examples:

- At the moment we store one address per company, but at one point we might want to store multiple addresses. (1 - 1 relationship transforms to 1 - n, or even n - n)
- Companies in different industries have very different attributes, e.g. for we have a lot of NULL-fields in our relational schema at the moment.
- Different degrees of information available, e.g. for some companies we only know the CEO's name, which could be stored in a single attribute of the company. For other companies we might want to use a relationship to a Person relation, because we have a photo, birthdate, CV etc... (the schema is not fixed)

What kind of database would be suited for such a task? I've looked into MongoDB, Neo4J, OrientDB. Some requirements which are important for us:

- No license fee for non-open-source commercial projects
- Should scale to storing 100GB - 1000TB, while executing OLAP queries for displaying a web interface (company query interface) in millisecond range